# Rotating around circle set degrees and positions.

Tags: jquery

i've been working getting divs to rotate around a circle to a set point.

- **Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TMuD5/2/**

However, I seem to have hit the end of my skill level. I am only a junior in JS/JQuery so please be gentle.

If you look at the Fiddle you will see four links at the bottom. If you click the first one which is rotate the boxes one space to the left. It works great. However it only works once. I have used:

```
$("#box" + i).data('position', degreeRot);
```

to add the currently location to a data attribute but it doesn't seem to be working. I wouldnt even recommend pressing the right button.

so, I have a few questions, if you wouldn't mind helping me out.

---

- **1)** Why isn't it adding the new degree to the data-position attribute? and how can I get it to do so that it will continue to go round, once pace at a time.
- **2)** I used **-=** for the boxes to go right, but they dont. Why is that?
- **3)** How can I get it to move 2 or 3 spaces at a time?

---

Thank you in advance. I really would appreciate all help and advice :)

Comment: Maybe try $("#box" + i).attr('data-position', degreeRot);

Comment: That didnt work either, now only box one moves in the first click: http://jsfiddle.net/TMuD5/3/

Comment: Sorry, see my revised reply. I had it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a lot of bugs, but in particular, I think you're over-complicating it by using the left/right stuff. Just use a positive or negative numeric value to indicate the amount to rotate:

```
<p class="worldMenuPosition " data-spaces="-1" id="box1">Rotate one space left</p>
<p class="worldMenuPosition" data-spaces="1" id="box2">Rotate 1 space right</p>
<p class="worldMenuPosition " data-spaces="-2" id="box1">Rotate two spaces left</p>
<p class="worldMenuPosition" data-spaces="2" id="box2">Rotate 2 spaces right</p>
```

Once you switch to that approach, the code can be progressively refactored down to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentRotation = -35,
        rotationIncrement = 35;

    $(".worldMenuPosition").click(function () {
        var spaces = $(this).data("spaces");

        rotateToDirection(spaces * rotationIncrement);
    });

    function rotateToDirection(deg) {
        currentRotation += deg;

        positionBoxes();
    }

    function rotateTo(deg, box) {
        var bplate = ["translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(", deg,
                      "deg) translateY(-200px) rotate(", -5, "deg)"];

        $(box).css({
            "transform": bplate.join("")
        });
    }

    function positionBoxes() {
        $(".worldSection").each(function (index, element) {
            rotateTo(currentRotation + (index * rotationIncrement), element);
        });
    }

    // Initialize positions
    positionBoxes();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TMuD5/9/

You asked for an explanation of the bugs, so here's a bit of an explanation.

Well, if we look just at the "left" branch of your code, it's changing the `data-position` of all 4 buttons every time you click the "One space left" button. The first time you click the "One space left" button, it rotates everything 35 degrees to the left, and updates the `data-position` attributes of all 4 buttons to go through these sequences of values as you click the "One space left" button:

```
box1 - -70, -35, 0, 35, 70, ...
box2 - 0, 70, 140, 210, 280, ...
box3 - -70, 35, 140, 245, 350, ...
box4 - 0, 140, 280, 420, 560, ...
```

So the next time you click "One space left", it rotates the bunch to the -35 degree position (which is one space to the right), then 0 degrees, then 35 degrees, etc. And so it goes that every click rotates the system 35 degrees to the *right*.

The "right" branch of your code suffers from a similar problem, but it's even worse since you are subtracting 35 on each iteration. This causes all the boxes to change position and rotate to the left.

Comment: hey, i'm new to JS - can you explain to me what the bugs are so I could avoid them for the future?

Comment: Added some explanation above. It's really a matter of thinking through the algorithm and making sense that it is logically consistent.

Comment: Thank you very helpful. Do you think you could give me a hint or pointer in the right direction how to make it a little smoother? it seems to jump initially.

Comment: @user3596752 I'm afraid I don't know about that. I think you know more about these CSS transformations than I do. :)